# Error while installing NLTK dataset - nltk.download

Tags: 14.04, python3

I've ubuntu 14.04(64-bit) installed on my machine.

I'm trying to install NLTK supporting packages using the commands

```
import nltk
nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128', ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))
nltk.download()
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
[Errno -2] Name or service not known
False
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does your system actually require use of a proxy? you know that `proxy.example.com` is meant to be replaced by your actual proxy host, right?

Comment: I replaced proxy.example.com with my proxy host.